# Definition of Range with dynamic indexes VBA

Tags: vba, range

I am fighting with generation of the charts in MS Excel by using VBA.

Here is my one sub-prodcedure of my code>

```
Sub fundamentalChart()
Dim fundamental As Chart
Dim trData As Range
Dim Qc1 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim clmLetter As String

'*******************************
'just for testing
Dim clmNumber(10) As Integer
clmNumber(1) = 43
'{43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70}
WSName = "2030184"
QcCount = 10
'*******************************

Set trData = Worksheets(WSName).Range("$D$1:$D$431224, $G$1:$G$431224")
Set fundametnal = Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=trData
ActiveChart.Name = WSName & "Fundamental"

For i = 1 To QcCount

Set Qc1 = Worksheets(WSName).Range(Cells(1, clmNumber(i)), Cells(43124, clmNumber(i))) 
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Qc" & i
        .Values = Qc1
        .XValues = Worksheets(WSName).Range("$D$1:$D$431224")
End With
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to add the new series collection. I have a problem with definition of the RANGE for the Values (QC1). In my code, clmNumber (that is stated above explicitly) is an (public) array which reaches different dimension and contains the different values (it point out the column numbers containing the values for the series).

How can I define the range when column index will gain the different values (stored in clmNumber)?

Thank you.

V.

Comment: You have a couple typos I noticed like `Set fundametnal = Charts.Add` should be `Set fundamental = Charts.Add`.  I would also Dim QcCount as Integer.  When I do charts and change the data I get access to the SeriesCollection formula and edit it that way.  Here is a line of code that may help `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = "=SERIES(,'Sheet1'!$A$34:$A$400,'Sheet1'!$" & ColumnLetter(n) & "$34:$" & ColumnLetter(n) & "$400,1)"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I transformed the actual numeric column index value into the letter value by using `clmLetter = Chr(Int((clmNumber(i) - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(((clmNumber(i) - 1) Mod 26) + 65)`. Then I tried to use your approach with formula > `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = _
"=SERIES(,'2030184'!$D$1:$D$43124,'2030184'!$" & clmLetter & "$1:$" & clmLetter & "$43124,1)`.... however, it contains some error. RunTime Error 1004. V.

Comment: You may be missing an ending quote.  [This link](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/) may help you.  Jon mentions something about XY charts throwing an error when you edit the Series Formula too.  HTH.

Comment: Ok I still can't find a suitable way how to fix it... The problem is that I have the the column number saved as variable. And using column number as variable - either number or matching letter - I can't formulate the input range for the new series. Any idea?? Thank you.

Comment: I stepped through some of your code and noticed you did not Dim QcCount or WSName.  You should add Option Explicit to the top of your module.  You also have an issue around the line `Set fundametnal = Charts.Add`  This line adds a Chart to the Chart Objects I believe and it puts the chart in its own Worksheet.  Then you have a problem when you get to `Set Qc1 = Worksheets(WSName).Range(Cells(1, clmNumber(i)), Cells(43124, clmNumber(i)))`  Cells is not fully referenced and it doesn't know which sheet you are referring to.  Put some breakpoints in and look at what is happening in the worksheet.